# Using big integers in sequelizeJS and postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, biginteger

I have a problem using sequelizeJS and PostgreSQL.

In the database I have a field with the value 11681748404404449. But in JS and I get 11681748404404448. That is, the value is rounded because it has a greater length. I would like to JS translate it to a string, but as I see it I immediately get an incorrect value from the driver PG. Possible in the sequelizejs has a type conversion like -

```
SELECT fieldName::text FROM ...
```

Answer (score -1):

> But in JS and I get 11681748404404448

What does it even mean? JavaScript is 32-bit, it cannot give you a number of such magnitude.

`PG` driver returns 64-bit integers as strings always. I can't say what `Sequelize` is doing on top of that, if anything.

You would need to clarify first of all what you mean when you say you are getting such big numbers, as JavaScript doesn't even support those.